# wrap_content for ListView height and width

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I would like to restrict the height and width of a `ListView`, wrapping the height based on the number of children's and wrapping the width  based on width  of list view row.

So far, I have been able to restrict the height of the ListView. The code I'm using for restricting height is:

```
listview.setLayoutParams(new linealayout.layoutparams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0,1));
```

How can I also restrict the width?

Comment: don't use `wrap_content` for a listview's height. it has to calculate its height based all the children in the listview before settling on a value. lord forbid it should change dynamically.

Comment: @mango Actually, in this youtube video [ http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CD4QtwIwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DwDBM6wVEO70&ei=hr8wUdeFC8jUswb9nYGQDA&usg=AFQjCNGAklAgezvQNN0PVmomzRjd7ci2uQ&sig2=_7VpK_V8xG2D5RcnkOU-6A ] android devs say they should look at all the children, but in practise they choose only 3 and infer the others are like those 3.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you should be more specific about your desired screen look/view

**But when it comes to listview I would say never use 20,30 dp to set width and height just use weight and wrap_content to make it flexible.**

see below code example this may help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ListView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

*let me know if you still have any trouble to get this one.*

Comment: thanks for reply.But , the above suggested method is not working.Check this link for screen shot .[http://i.imgur.com/vCzjM.png?1]

Comment: @sha plz check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090185/how-to-make-a-list-view-to-show-only-3-items) one