# Display limited items on listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview with 1000 datas in it. I want to display only 10 items at a time and when my cursor is at the last position , next scrolling must make my cursor to navigate at the first position and the next 10 items needs to display.My listview is based on [this](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter) link and i referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090185/how-to-make-a-list-view-to-show-only-3-items), butcouldn't achieve what i want. Help me in achieving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a cursor you could use the limit query. Where by you could keep track of the current limit value.

Say for example. you first have select * from table_name limit 0,10.. firstLimit = 0;, and since the counter 10 is fixed, on scroll you could determine if the last item is visible and compare it with the cursor count, and increment firstLimit by 10, such that your new query would be select * from table_name where limit (firstLimit+10), 10. since this will return a new cursor, you will have to use a merge cursor and merge the first cursor and the new one, and call swapCursor on the adapter and pass the merged cursor.

In this scenario, for cursor maintenance, the old cursor = mergedCursor. and new cursor will be the one with the new query.

This however will lead to the same case where all items at one point in time will be visible to the user.

To prevent this you could use a load  more option and only show 10 records at a time ... always.

----> Edited: here is an example

Assume you have the necessary database related files up and running. and a listview with a custom cursor adapter, do this:

```
lstView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0) {
            start = end; end += 10; 
            cursorLoadMore = dbOperations.getData(YourActivity.this,start,end);
        }

        cursors = new Cursor[] {cursorLoadMore, cursor};
        MergeCursor mergeCursor = new MergeCursor(cursors);
        myListAdapter.swapCursor(mergeCursor);
        myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        cursor = mergeCursor;
    }
});
```

As you scroll new records will be displayed.

Comment: can u please explain with an example and one more thing when my cursor reaches the bottom the next scrolling should lead that to reach the top

Comment: can you post an example so that i can understand it better

Answer (score 0):

In Base Adapter, initially take i=10; then use this "i" in `getCount()` method of `BaseAdapter`.

```
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return i;
}
```

And in your "show more" `Button` click Increment the i, then call adapter.

Ex:

```
i=i+10;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```