# Load More when user scrolls to bottom of the listview with CursorAdapter is possible?

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

Just out of curiosity wanted to know if we can implement Load More functionality
when user scrolls to bottom of the listview using CursorAdapter. I have huge data almost in millions. I am using cursoradapter and i dont want to change the architecture already out there in my application.

I know we can implement this using BaseAdapter and ArrayListAdapter

Any opinion or threads leading to this highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573489/android-endless-scrolling-listview-and-cursor

Comment: BaseAdapter is the efficient in handling the load more because you can custom loading in required no of records

Comment: @impathuri Yes but shifting from CursorAdapter to BaseAdapter is not easy task in my case.

Comment: @ShabbirPanjesha https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/an-analysis-between-baseadapters-and-cursoradapters/    i think u have to take challange on this for the first time

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to implement `EndlessAdapter` search the **EndlessAdapter** example on google.Here is commonsware demo project.

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless